# MEF -- Any way to initialize it with parameters?

Tags: c#, parameters, initialization, export, mef

```
[Export]
public class MyViewModel : NotificationObject
{
    public MyViewModel(Foo foo)
    {
        DoWorkCommand = new DelegateCommand(DoWork);

        MyFoo = foo;
    }

    [Import]
    private IBarService MyBarService { get; set; }

    public Foo MyFoo { get; private set; }

    public DelegateCommand DoWorkCommand { get; set; }

    public void DoWork()
    {
        MyBarService.DoSomething(MyFoo);
    }
}
```

How can I get an instance of the MyViewModel class while also being able to pass in parameters? I thought maybe the `ExportFactor<T>` would let me pass in some parameters, but it doesn't. So, is there some pattern that accounts for what I'm hoping to achieve?

Simply doing a new() won't cut it because the `MyBarService` stays null then. I thought about removing the `ExportAttribute` and using `ComponentInitializer.SatisfyImports(this)`, which let's me use new(), but that kind of makes it so I have to new() everything. I was kind of hoping for a best of both worlds... having some type of way to Import something with parameters. That way I am still decoupled, but am able to generate instances of my ViewModel with the parameters set.

Answer (score 0):

MEF supports depedency injection, for instance, I could do:

```
[ImportingConstructor]
public MyViewModel(Foo foo)
{

}
```

And MEF will automatically try and inject an instance of `Foo` into my constructor.  Perhaps you could use this mechanism to inject your required services into your composed parts?

Comment: No. This won't work unless Foo is marked with the ExportAttribute, at which point I could just as well mark the field with the ImportAttribute.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass some parameters from the importer to the exporter, then you can put an Initialize method on the class or interface you are exporting.  Something like this:

```
[Export]
public class MyViewModel : NotificationObject
{
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        DoWorkCommand = new DelegateCommand(DoWork);
    }

    public void Initialize(Foo foo)
    {
        MyFoo = foo;
    }

    [Import]
    private IBarService MyBarService { get; set; }

    public Foo MyFoo { get; private set; }

    public DelegateCommand DoWorkCommand { get; set; }

    public void DoWork()
    {
        MyBarService.DoSomething(MyFoo);
    }
}
```

Then use an `ExportFactory` on the import side, and call the `Initialize` method after creating a new instance of the export.

Comment: This works but could lead to issues: What if it were `public readonly int SomeNumber;` ... Initialize would not be able to set it, whereas a constructor would.